# How to find the jacobian of this function?

Tags: convex-optimization

$\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}$

I want to find the Jacobian of the following function $D:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$:

$$
  D(p) = \argmin_{x} \left(C(x) - x \cdot p\right)\ \text{ s.t. } x \in X
$$

where $C$ is twice differentiable and $X$ is a convex set.

According to [Bertsekas, Non linear Programming](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1057/palgrave.jors.2600425?journalCode=tjor20), p12, without the constraint set $X$ we can apply sensitivity analysis.

Let $f(x, p) = C(x) - x \cdot p$. Treat $p$ is a parameter to the minimization problem involving $x$:

$$
  \min_x f(x, p)\ \text{ s.t. } x \in \mathbb{R}^n
$$

Assuming the optimal point $x^*$ can be expressed as a unique and differentiable function of $p$, $x(p)$, and $(\nabla^{2}_{xx}f)^{-1}$ exists, then:

$$
  \nabla x(p) = - (\nabla^{2}_{xa}f(x(p), p))(\nabla^{2}_{xx}f(x(p), p))^{-1}
$$

Substituting the original objective function back in:

$$
  \nabla x(p) = (\nabla^{2}_{xx}C(x(p)))^{-1}
$$

I.e. the Jacobian is the inverse Hessian of $C$. If we know a given $x^*$, $\nabla D(p) = (\nabla^{2}_{xx}C(x^*))^{-1}$ in the vicinity (open sphere) around $x^*$.

My issue is I need to account for the convex constraint set, $X$, and I'm unsure how to do that. If $X$ is formed by a set of inequality constraints $g(x) \le 0$, we can apply the above sensitivity analysis using the Lagrangian first order conditions (assuming Lagrangian multipliers exist). However, in my case $X$ is just and arbitrary convex set.

Comment: you can relate your answer to the concave conjugate of $U$

Comment: Note updated question and function $U$ referred to by @LinAlg is now $C$, but crux of question is the same.